# Onclick add html content and remove it by clicking "delete" link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some issue, help me please to find where is the mistake.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents .row-wrap').size() + 1;

    $('body').on('click', '.add-item', function() {
            $('<div class="row-wrap cf"><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><input type="text" placeholder="Наименование" name="item_name' + i +'"></div><div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><input type="text" placeholder="Количество" name="item_count' + i +'"></div><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><input type="text" placeholder="Требования" name="item_demand' + i +'"></div><div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12"><a href="#" class="delete-item">delete</a></div></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('.col-md-1').on('click', '.delete-item', function() { 
        event.preventDefault();
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('.row-wrap').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
});

 });
```

On click to "add-item" jquery create new row with some html. And by click on "delete item" I need to remove this parent `.row-wrap` except first row.
Here is [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/w4ksgynj/)
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are using .on() with event delegation syntax, it is not working as the element to which the event is binded is created dynamically.

You are registering the handler to `col-md-1` which is the parent of the delete button, but that element also is created dynamically so when you say `$('.col-md-1').on('click',...)`, the handler is not added to any element.

To use event delegation, the handler should be added to a pre-existing element(ancestor of the dynamic element) with the dynamic element selector as the second parameter.

In your case since you are adding the dynamic contents to the `scntDiv` element, you can bind the handler to that element like

```
      scntDiv.on('click', '.delete-item', function () {
          event.preventDefault();
          if (i > 2) {
              $(this).parents('.row-wrap').remove();
              i--;
          }
          return false;
      });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c9qftqse/)

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept the answer after 11 minutes)